# Is there any idiom or phrase for "I am going to have a fulfilling day tomorrow"?

Tags: phrases, idioms

Is there any idiom or phrase for "I am going to have a fulfilling day tomorrow"??

I am writing an English diary to practice writing skill, and I tried to end it up saying myself that "I will have a fulfilling day tomorrow". I wanted it to sound determined, but I am not sure if there is a idiom or phrase for it.

Comment: Tomorrow is gonna be a good day.   I’m really looking forward to tomorrow.

Comment: *Tomorrow I will have my day*.  or *Tomorrow will be my day*.  Derives from "*Every dog has its day*," a proverb dating from the 16th century.  http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/had+its+day%2c+has

Comment: *Tomorrow will be fulfilling.*

Answer (score 3):

Even though the Guys have helpfully offered some synonyms for your own phrase no, there isn’t any idiom or particular phrase for that.

For a recognised idiom, the *closest* you could get would prolly be *tomorrow is another day* but only in contradistinction, if for instance today has been a bad day and particularly when today has been very bad.
(See https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=annie+tommorrow+is+anothe+day&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB718GB718&oq=annie+tommorrow+is+anothe+day&aqs=chrome..69i57.5111j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 )

For a phrase, your own *I am going to have a fulfilling day tomorrow* is fine in and of itself. It needs no alteration.

Meanwhile please consider:
I am *keeping* an English diary to practice *my writing skills/writing…, and* I tried to *end today’s entry* saying *to* myself: "I will have a fulfilling day tomorrow.”

I wanted it to sound determined, but I am not sure if there is *an* idiom or phrase for *that*.

Comment: +1 for _tomorrow is another day_ which would have been my response (as the _closest_ option).

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of : "Tomorrow I will be in full gear" ?

Answer (score 0):

Tomorrow is going to be a great day.

I'm looking forward to tomorrow.

I can't wait for tomorrow.

Tomorrow promises to be great.

Bring on tomorrow.